# How to get arguments from an emitted event in hardhat?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I've been trying to get the arguments of an event that was emitted from a contract function call. But had no luck so far.

based on what i've found something like this should work:

```
  const tx = await eventEmitter.emitBothEvents(42, "foo");

  const receipt = await tx.wait()

  for (const event of receipt.events) {
    console.log(`Event ${event.event} with args ${event.args}`);
  }
```

(https://github.com/fvictorio/hardhat-examples/blob/master/reading-events/scripts/getEventsFromTx.js)

But `receipt.events` is always undefined no matter what function i call.
So.. been there any updates to this or something? any other ways i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

```
const tx = await myContract.myFunction()
  result = await tx.wait()

  function findEventArgs(logs, eventName) {
    let _event = null;
  
    for (const event of logs) {
      if (event.fragment && event.fragment.name === eventName) {
        _event = event.args;
      }
    }
    return _event
  }

  console.log(findEventArgs(result.logs, "myEventName"))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**